# If $\overline H$ is a subgroup of $G$, is $H \subset G$ a subgroup also?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

The following is Proposition $2.1(c)$ of Folland's *A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis*.

> Let $G$ be a topological group. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then so is $\overline{H}$.

The proof uses net convergence. If $x,y\in \overline H$, there are nets $\{x_\alpha\}$ and $\{y_\alpha\}$ converging to $x$ and $y$ respectively. The net $\{(x_\alpha,y_\alpha)\}$ converges to $(x,y)$ in $G \times G$, and so, by the continuity of the map $(a,b) \mapsto ab$, the net $\{x_\alpha y_\alpha^{-1}\}$ converges to $xy^{-1}$. Therefore, $xy^{-1} \in \overline H$, and $\overline H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

**Question:** I wish to know if the converse is true, i.e., if $H$ is a *subset* of $G$, and $\overline{H}$ is a subgroup of $G$, is $H$ necessarily a subgroup of $G$?  In general, I suspect this to be false, though concrete counterexamples would help. For which class of topological groups is the converse true?

Comment: No. If $G=\mathbb R,$ you can take $H$ to be the union of the positive rationals and the negative irrationals. Then $H$ is not a subgroup, but $\overline H$ is a subgroup, namely all of $\mathbb R.$.

Comment: An even easier example, $G=\mathbb{R}$ and $H=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a class of topological groups for which this is true?

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic If the topology is discrete it is trivially true. Otherwise it is always false - take an element $g\in G$ such that $\{g\}$ is not open and define $H=G\setminus\{g\}$, just like in my previous example.

Comment: @Mark A related question occurs to me.  If $H$ is a closed subgroup with non-empty interior, does it follow that $\operatorname{int} H$ also is a subgroup?

Comment: @RobertShore Yes, because if $H$ is any subgroup which has nonempty interior then $H$ is open (actually, closed as well), and so equals its interior. Indeed, let $U$ be a nonempty subset of $G$ such that $U\subseteq H$, and let any $u\in U$. Then for any $h\in H$, the set $hu^{-1}U$ is an open set in $G$ which is contained in $H$ and contains $h$, and so $h\in int(H)$.